# How to Store (and Retrieve) Non-English Characters (e.g. Hindi, Czech, Arabic etc.) in SQL Server in Android

Tags: android, utf-8, server, character

I have a problem in Android Programming.I need to post non-English character to server  and get non-English character from server in my android code and when I try to do this I face with some characters like "   Ø§Ø§Ù†Ù†Ù†Ù†ØªØ¨Ùˆ". anybody can help me?
here is codes for post data :

String data=URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(User,"UTF-8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("matn","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Matn,"UTF-8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("status","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Status,"UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to support multi-language, you need to have corresponding locale strings available in xml/strings files...
If it is just a few characters like font icons, you can store them in strings resource file.

Check your device whether the language is installed, or try using

`Html.fromHtml( "<html><body>"+response+"</body></html>");`